# Deploying reactjs app to aws amplify results in white screen with error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, create-react-app, aws-amplify

I am trying to deploy a reactjs app to aws amplify and everything works final on localhost and in incognito browser window, just when I access my app url in a regular browser I get this error
[image]

If I clear my browser cookies and access the url its fine but everytime I deploy a new build folder it goes back to this. I tried almost every suggestion I could find on the internet but it still occurs.

Solutions I tried :

1. Setting up PUBLIC_URL in .env file.
2. Deploying through S3 bucket instead of drag and drop.
3. Adding `<Router basename='/index.html'>` to my code.
4. Adding homepage pointing to my domain in package.json.
5. Adding homepage pointing to '.' in package.json
6. Adding homepage pointing to './' in package.json
7. Adding the above homepage variations to manifest.json in public folder.

Details about my environment and observations :

1. I am hosting the app on aws amplify with custom domain via Route 53.
2. App works absolutely fine without any issues on incognito browser - so if there was an issue with the code it should break in incognito as well correct?
3. The work-around is to clear browser cookies and hit the url again but its undesirable coz this is a production environment and every time I deploy a change I cannot ask my users to clear cookies and try again - changes should be picked up by the browser instantly.
4. Following is my compiled index.html

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Vaccination Verification Made Easy" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://vaxtone.com/logo192.png" />
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <link rel="manifest" href="https://vaxtone.com/manifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials">
    <title>VaxTone</title>
    <link href="https://vaxtone.com/static/css/2.f4136754.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://vaxtone.com/static/css/main.dd527d15.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>"serviceWorker" in navigator && window.addEventListener("load", (function () { navigator.serviceWorker.register("serviceWorker.js").then((function (e) { console.log("ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ", e.scope) }), (function (e) { console.log("ServiceWorker registration failed: ", e) })) }))</script>
    <script>!function (e) { function t(t) { for (var n, a, i = t[0], c = t[1], l = t[2], s = 0, p = []; s < i.length; s++)a = i[s], Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, a) && o[a] && p.push(o[a][0]), o[a] = 0; for (n in c) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(c, n) && (e[n] = c[n]); for (f && f(t); p.length;)p.shift()(); return u.push.apply(u, l || []), r() } function r() { for (var e, t = 0; t < u.length; t++) { for (var r = u[t], n = !0, i = 1; i < r.length; i++) { var c = r[i]; 0 !== o[c] && (n = !1) } n && (u.splice(t--, 1), e = a(a.s = r[0])) } return e } var n = {}, o = { 1: 0 }, u = []; function a(t) { if (n[t]) return n[t].exports; var r = n[t] = { i: t, l: !1, exports: {} }; return e[t].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, a), r.l = !0, r.exports } a.e = function (e) { var t = [], r = o[e]; if (0 !== r) if (r) t.push(r[2]); else { var n = new Promise((function (t, n) { r = o[e] = [t, n] })); t.push(r[2] = n); var u, i = document.createElement("script"); i.charset = "utf-8", i.timeout = 120, a.nc && i.setAttribute("nonce", a.nc), i.src = function (e) { return a.p + "static/js/" + ({}[e] || e) + "." + { 3: "44b4c37d" }[e] + ".chunk.js" }(e); var c = new Error; u = function (t) { i.onerror = i.onload = null, clearTimeout(l); var r = o[e]; if (0 !== r) { if (r) { var n = t && ("load" === t.type ? "missing" : t.type), u = t && t.target && t.target.src; c.message = "Loading chunk " + e + " failed.\n(" + n + ": " + u + ")", c.name = "ChunkLoadError", c.type = n, c.request = u, r[1](c) } o[e] = void 0 } }; var l = setTimeout((function () { u({ type: "timeout", target: i }) }), 12e4); i.onerror = i.onload = u, document.head.appendChild(i) } return Promise.all(t) }, a.m = e, a.c = n, a.d = function (e, t, r) { a.o(e, t) || Object.defineProperty(e, t, { enumerable: !0, get: r }) }, a.r = function (e) { "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 }) }, a.t = function (e, t) { if (1 & t && (e = a(e)), 8 & t) return e; if (4 & t && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e; var r = Object.create(null); if (a.r(r), Object.defineProperty(r, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: e }), 2 & t && "string" != typeof e) for (var n in e) a.d(r, n, function (t) { return e[t] }.bind(null, n)); return r }, a.n = function (e) { var t = e && e.__esModule ? function () { return e.default } : function () { return e }; return a.d(t, "a", t), t }, a.o = function (e, t) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t) }, a.p = "https://vaxtone.com/", a.oe = function (e) { throw console.error(e), e }; var i = this["webpackJsonpvaxtone1.0"] = this["webpackJsonpvaxtone1.0"] || [], c = i.push.bind(i); i.push = t, i = i.slice(); for (var l = 0; l < i.length; l++)t(i[l]); var f = c; r() }([])</script>
    <script src="https://vaxtone.com/static/js/2.3e8f6948.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="https://vaxtone.com/static/js/main.6ccb123a.chunk.js"></script>
</body>
<style>
    body::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none
    }

    body {
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        scrollbar-width: none
    }
</style>

</html>
```

5. I used the `create-react-app` command to create the reactjs app and use `npm run build` to generate the build folder for deployment.
6. I use a service worker to implement progressive-web-app features - could it be something related to my service worker?

Any help on how to resolve this or what do you think is happening would be a big big help .Thanks.

Comment: As the error is quite generic is difficult to say if the source is this but: Try by making sure you don't have odd rewrites and redirects, if you only have the "default" like domain.com to www.domain.com it is ok, nothing else should be there. When I add some wrong rewrites it yields with this error you mentioned

Comment: I'm running into the exact same problem. Checked everything and tried similar things as segFault but nothing worked.

Comment: Hi, Have you fixed this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your package json file either does not have homepage set or the value for homepage matches your AWS Amplify URL. I had the same issue and this resolved it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).